# Linux , zombie process и Инкрементный pid

Tags: linux, консоль, процесс

Решил я глянуть зомби процессы

```
 ps aux | grep -w Z
```

вывело мне это :

```
root     12653  0.0  0.0   3792   520 pts/0    S+   16:59   0:00 grep --color=auto -w Z
```

решил убить,но процесса не существует. Выяснил , каждый раз ps aux | grep -w Z возвращает  pid больше на 1 предыдущего. Не подскажете ,что это может быть?

Comment: Это не зомби-процесс, а часть командной строки `grep`-а (`grep --color=auto -w Z`), которым вы фильтруете вывод. То есть ваша команда обнаружила саму себя (ну, почти).

Comment: Благодарю) уже думал кто то брутфорсит)